# MySQL replication recovery

Tags: mysql-replication

I can't sync the slave server after master server crashed. Could you please advise if the recovery is possible (without data/transaction lost) or do I have to create a new slave server?

Please note that I stooped slave after this error:

```
mysql> SHOW SLAVE STATUS \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: 
                  Master_Host: 192.168.1.1
                  Master_User: slave
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000010
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 940132528
               Relay_Log_File: cb1s-relay-bin.000001
                Relay_Log_Pos: 4
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000010
             Slave_IO_Running: No
            Slave_SQL_Running: No
              Replicate_Do_DB: 
          Replicate_Ignore_DB: 
           Replicate_Do_Table: 
       Replicate_Ignore_Table: 
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: 
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: 
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error: 
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 940132528
              Relay_Log_Space: 107
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File: 
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File: 
           Master_SSL_CA_Path: 
              Master_SSL_Cert: 
            Master_SSL_Cipher: 
               Master_SSL_Key: 
        Seconds_Behind_Master: NULL
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 1236
                Last_IO_Error: Got fatal error 1236 from master when reading data from binary log: 'Client requested master to start replication from impossible position; the first event 'mysql-bin.000010' at 940132528, the last event read from './mysql-bin.000010' at 4, the last byte read from './mysql-bin.000010' at 4.'
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error: 
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids: 
             Master_Server_Id: 1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Logs:

```
120711 13:04:24 [Note] Slave I/O thread: connected to master 'user@192.168.1.1:3306',replication started in log 'mysql-bin.000010' at position 940132528
120711 13:04:24 [ERROR] Error reading packet from server: Client requested master to start replication from impossible position; the first event 'mysql-bin.000010' at 940132528, the last event read from './mysql-bin.000010' at 4, the last byte read from './mysql-bin.000010' at 4. ( server_errno=1236)
120711 13:04:24 [ERROR] Slave I/O: Got fatal error 1236 from master when reading data from binary log: 'Client requested master to start replication from impossible position; the first event 'mysql-bin.000010' at 940132528, the last event read from './mysql-bin.000010' at 4, the last byte read from './mysql-bin.000010' at 4.', Error_code: 1236
120711 13:04:24 [Note] Slave I/O thread exiting, read up to log 'mysql-bin.000010', position 940132528
120711 13:04:24 [Note] Slave SQL thread initialized, starting replication in log 'mysql-bin.000010' at position 940132528, relay log './cb1s-relay-bin.000026' position: 940132674
120711 13:05:08 [Note] Error reading relay log event: slave SQL thread was killed
120711 13:06:20 [Note] Slave SQL thread initialized, starting replication in log 'mysql-bin.000010' at position 940132528, relay log './cb1s-relay-bin.000027' position: 4
```

Comment: The solution is explained [here](http://mysqldba.blogspot.com/2007/04/client-asks-master-to-start-replication.html) and [here](http://dev.kafol.net/2011/09/mysql-error-1236-client-requested.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to *create* a new slave. You just would need to replay the master's data and re-set the replication coordinates on the slave (`CHANGE MASTER TO ...`) as [described in the MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-howto.html).

You might get the data off the master without stopping the database by specifying the *--master-data=2* option to your mysqldump call - this would write the replication coordinates of your dump into the `mysqldump` output.

Note that running mysqldump *could* still mean a downtime for your database-backed application as all tables would be read-locked for the duration of the dump.

Another option would be to just reset the replication coordinates as [suggested by David Schwartz in his comment to your question](https://serverfault.com/questions/406761/mysql-replication-recovery/406854#comment426555_406761) and replay all table's data to the slave(s) using [pt-table-sync from the Percona Toolkit](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-table-sync.html) to ensure integrity.